# When appending to a List of JSON Objects in python, why is it duplicating only the "2nd layer" objects?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list

Here is my code.

```
def generateNewDevices(numofdevices):
    global simulated_devices
    for x in range(numofdevices):
        new_device = reference_device.copy()
        new_device["accel"]["accx"] = random.randint(-32768, 32767)
        new_device["accel"]["accy"] = random.randint(-32768, 32767)
        new_device["accel"]["accz"] = random.randint(-32768, 32767)
        new_device["location"]["gpsla"] = random.uniform(MINLAT, MAXLAT)
        new_device["location"]["gpslo"] = random.uniform(MINLON, MAXLON)
        new_device["temp"] = random.randint(-127, 127)
        new_device["status"] = random.randint(0, 1)
        str1 = new_device["deviceName"]
        str1 = str1[:-3]
        str2 = str(x).zfill(3)
        str1 += str2
        new_device["deviceName"] = str1
        node_red_send(URL, new_device)
        print(new_device)
        simulated_devices.append(new_device)

generateNewDevices(3)
for x in range(len(simulated_devices)):
    print(simulated_devices[x])
```

Why when printing through the list of values at the end, does the list show the "new device" data for appended JSON objects "1 layer deep" (temp, status and name) but duplicate the data for "2 layers deep" (accx, accy, gpsla)?

The .copy()s are in there because I was having issues with python append duplicating all the values at first. Is this some variation of the same issue? I even tried .copy()ing right before appending to the list. (I come from a c/c++ background so I do not fully understand why python does some of its things)

Any help appreciated.

Kr, apuri123.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anyone will end up here when searching for an answer, but in case you do, you are looking for "deepcopy":

```
import copy
original = {} #object with as many objects within objects as you want
myCopy = copy.deepcopy(original)
```

Google "python deepcopy" and you should be able to find what you are looking for.